# Does an antimagic field also suppress the effects of supernatural abilities like change shape and invisibility (su)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I already know the antimagic field suppresses the usage of the supernatural abilities, but i want to know what happens to some effects like an alternate form when using change shape or supernatural invisibility.

If a creature that used the ability enters the antimagic field, what happens?

Does a kitsune with the fox shape feat, in fox shape, revert to fox folk form or remains restrained to the fox form inside the antimagic field?

Does a sprite with supernatural invisibility becomes visible or does she remain invisible and cannot become visible inside the antimagic field?

Does a titan with change shape in human form revert to titan?

The downside of assuming they don't lose the alternate form or become visible is that makes the su overpowered.

The downside of assuming they lose the alternate form and become visible is detect magic will detect such creatures with ease, making those su underpowered.

Comment: A SU ability is not there because of its powers or to make a creature powerful. It usually isn't learned or aquired by a creature, it merely reflects the nature of a creature and things it can do. So yes, it can be detected with detect magic but a) not everyone runs around with detect magic spells ready and b) some caster still needs to have reason to suspect magic. So a titan in human form might appear perfectly normal and not hinting at the use of magic in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Yes**

Because as long as the effect has a duration and is magical, it will stop working inside an antimagic zone. And once you walk out of it (or the zone walks away) the magical effects return.

> **Antimagic** does not dispel magic; it suppresses it. Once a magical effect is no longer affected by the antimagic (the antimagic fades, the center of the effect moves away, and so on), the magic returns. **Spells that still have part of their duration left begin functioning again**, magic items are once again useful, and so forth.

Some spell effects, like [flesh to stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/flesh-to-stone), have no duration, are instantaneous effects (see bellow), which are not subject to [antimagic zone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Antimagic) because the spell already happened and what remains is the result of the spell.

The "*stone*" is not magical, its real.

Another example is the damage caused by a [Fireball](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball). The spell itself wouldnt work inside an antimagic zone, but the damage caused is instantaneous, once the spell is cast and the damage is taken, the remaining effects (health lost, burn wounds, ego hurt, etc) are not magical *per se*.

Shapechanging in general mimic the spells from the [polymorph school](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph), which do have a duration.

> **Timed Durations**
>   Many durations are measured in rounds, minutes, hours, or other increments. When the time is up, the magic goes away and the spell ends. If a spell's duration is variable, the duration is rolled secretly so the caster doesn't know how long the spell will last.

[Change Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Change-Shape-Su-) (From universal monster rules) says: This ability functions as a [Polymorph spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph), which has *Duration 1 min/level (D)*.

But *Change Shape* specifically clears it up that the creature can remain in that form **indefinitely** unless said otherwise. Meaning that it has a **long-lasting duration**.

> **Instantaneous**
>   The spell energy comes and goes the instant the spell is cast, *though the consequences might be long-lasting*.

[Called creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration-Calling) won't get dispelled either, because the spell that bought them to the material plane already did it's work, the creature is physically here and won't disapear in an antimagic zone. But a [summoned creature](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration-Summoning) will disapear as long as it remains "inside" the zone.

> **Calling**: a calling spell transports a creature from another plane to the plane you are on. The spell grants the creature the one-time ability to return to its plane of origin, although the spell may limit the circumstances under which this is possible. Creatures who are called actually die when they are killed; they do not disappear and reform, as do those brought by a summoning spell (see below). *The duration of a calling spell is instantaneous*, which means that the called creature **can't be dispelled**.

### Subquestions

> If a creature that used the ability enters the antimagic field, what happens?

The effect is on the creature? Or it was just the caster? The person with the active effect (it has duration left, even if undefined) will get surppressed.

> Does a kitsune with the fox shape feat, in fox shape, revert to fox folk form or remains restrained to the fox form inside the antimagic field?

Yes, because her fox shape is a polymorph effect with a duration.

> Does a sprite with supernatural invisibility becomes visible or does she remain invisible and cannot become visible inside the antimagic field?

Yes, she will become visible and won't be able to turn invisible again. The same will happen to an invisible stalker, they will show up as a ghostly vaguely-humanoid creature with no details (the picture we see in the bestiary), but they are no longer invisible.

> Does a titan with change shape in human form revert to titan?

Yes, because change shape is a magical effect that has a duration.

Answer (score 11):

> [Supernatural abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-) are not subject to spell resistance and do not function in areas where magic is suppressed or negated (such as an antimagic field).

They do not function in an antimagic field. If the invisible creature were to walk into an antimagic field, the effect would be suppressed and they would be become visible.

Comment: If you click on the hyperlink, you'll see a table that might be helpful for determining when dispel magic, spell resistance, antimagic field, or attacks of opportunities apply in cases where extraordinary abilities, supernatual abilities, and spell-like abilities are used.

Comment: I know the table. But i'm not asking for the ability but its effects.

Comment: I think the querent's wondering about how deep the word *function* goes. That is, does *do not function* mean the abilities just can't be activated, or does *do not function* mean already activated abilities are deactivated.

Comment: It is more like if the effects of supernatural abilities are part of the abilities or just mundane consequences.

Comment: Iv seen lots of examples where things cease working temporarily inside an antimagic zone. Then resume their effects when you go outside. That's what "surpressed" generally means.

Answer (score -1):

I usually try to think of what words *weren't* used to describe the effect. If supernatural abilities are "suppressed" then they're not "dispelled" so when you walk into the field, you temporarily lose your shapechange/invisibility/etc. When you step out, it's no longer suppressed and pops back on.

If the intent were for the ability to remain locked in whatever state or shape it was in when you entered the field, I would have phrased it as "suppresses ability to use supernatural abilities" not just "suppresses abilities".

Comment: Your answer is making me think if i have to rephrase my question. For some people to be in a different form is not a part of the supernatural ability but just an effect. Like flesh to stone spell, you cannot turn a person converted in stone back to normal by putting her in an antimagic field. With that interpretation the text does not need to change and the shapeshifted remains in her alternate form.

Comment: That is because flesh to stone has no duration, its an instantaneous effect, which is not subject to antimagic zone because it already happened. The "stone" is not magical, its real.

Comment: Shapechange mimics the spells from polymorph school, which do have a duration.

Comment: Called creatures won't get dispelled either, because the spell that bought them to the material plane already did it's work, the creature is physically here and won't disapear in an antimagic zone. But a summoned creature will disapear as long as it remains "inside" the zone.

Comment: Curses (such as from Bestow Curse or Blindness/Deafness) are also permanent and won't disapear inside an antimagic zone.

Comment: Change Shape (From universal monster rules) say: This ability functions as a polymorph spell, which says Duration 1 min/level (D). But Change Shape specifically clears it up that the creature can remain in that form indefinitely unless said otherwise.

Comment: Getting home i will format this into a proper answer, if someone hasnt done so yet. :D

Comment: Yes, @ShadowKras, format it properly and reach a final answer, cause i'm lost as it is now...